# Sum of expected value of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

If I have a random variable X, and then is $\frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{E[X]} = E[X]$ or $\frac {1}{n} E[X]$?

I thought, isn't E[X] independent of $i$ because expectation of X would be a value? Then shouldn't $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{E[X]}$ itself be $E[X]$? Or should I see $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{E[X_{i}]}$?

I'm confused...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be any sequence of random variables defined on some probability space. The expectation being linear, we always have
$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)$$
If, in addition, we also know that $X_i$ all have the same distribution (*) as some fixed random variable $X$, then in particular, $E(X_i)=E(X)$ for all $i$, so that
$$\sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nE(X)=\underbrace{E(X)+E(X)+\cdots E(X)}_n=nE(X)$$

(*) It is actually enough to assume that they all have the same expectation as $X$. They need not even be identically distributed.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{E[X]} =\frac{1}{n}\cdot n E[X]=E[X]$